# How to iterate through matrix and change it's values?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, matrix

I need to build a matrix with some values i have but as a tuple where i've a dictionary where the vales are coordinator and the keys are just an id, what i need to do is build a 5X6 matrix and append the values in
My code is like this:

```
DIC = {1: (0.0, 0.0), 6: (0.0, 0.14), 2: (0.14, 0.0), 7: (0.14, 0.14), 3: (0.28, 0.0), 8: (0.28, 0.14), 4: (0.42, 0.0), 9: (0.42, 0.14), 5: (0.56, 0.0), 10: (0.56, 0.14), 11: (0.0, 0.28), 12: (0.14, 0.28), 13: (0.28, 0.28), 14: (0.42, 0.28), 15: (0.56, 0.28), 16: (0.0, 0.42), 17: (0.14, 0.42), 18: (0.28, 0.42), 19: (0.42, 0.42), 20: (0.56, 0.42), 21: (0.0, 0.56), 22: (0.14, 0.56), 23: (0.28, 0.56), 24: (0.42, 0.56), 25: (0.56, 0.56), 26: (0.0, 0.7), 27: (0.14, 0.7), 28: (0.28, 0.7), 29: (0.42, 0.7), 30: (0.56, 0.71)}    
w, h = 5, 6
position = [[(tuple(DIC[element]) for element in DIC) for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 
print(position)
```

unfortunately i'm getting this when running the code

```
at 0x7fccc7ff37b0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3820>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3890>], [<generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3900>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3970>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff39e0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3a50>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3ac0>], [<generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3b30>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3ba0>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3c10>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3c80>, <generator object <listcomp>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7fccc7ff3cf0>]]
```

Anyone an idea how to get the values???

Comment: The question is unclear: how should be used the values in the dict?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited description, I made the assumption you want to use the index of your dictionary as the indices for your matrix. If this is the case, it appears your dictionary does not have a 0 index, so in the list comprehension below, you'll want to start your ranges from 1.

```
position = [ [ DIC[x*y] for x in range(1, w+1) ] for y in range(1, h+1) ]
position 
[[(0.0, 0.0), (0.14, 0.0), (0.28, 0.0), (0.42, 0.0), (0.56, 0.0)], [(0.14, 0.0), (0.42, 0.0), (0.0, 0.14), (0.28, 0.14), (0.56, 0.14)], [(0.28, 0.0), (0.0, 0.14), (0.42, 0.14), (0.14, 0.28), (0.56, 0.28)], [(0.42, 0.0), (0.28, 0.14), (0.14, 0.28), (0.0, 0.42), (0.56, 0.42)], [(0.56, 0.0), (0.56, 0.14), (0.56, 0.28), (0.56, 0.42), (0.56, 0.56)], [(0.0, 0.14), (0.14, 0.28), (0.28, 0.42), (0.42, 0.56), (0.56, 0.71)]]
```

Comment: Congratulations on your top-notch mind-reading abilities!!

Comment: thnx, but it's not doing the job i want it to do :(
i would also be happy with 2 matrices x and y with x and y coordinator from the dic

Answer (score 0):

( x for x in ...) is understood as a generator.

is not necessary to explicit tuple(), 'cause your data are already tuple

```
[[DIC[element] for element in DIC for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

This do the job

Comment: This doesn't really do what exactly i want, in my dict there are 30 elements, and i just need a matrix with 30 elements not more

Comment: So i think the question is not clear, are you searching for a 5x6x2 matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused by the use of parentheses instead of brackets in the inner comprehension:

`(tuple(DIC[element]) for element in DIC)` is an iterator.

`[tuple(DIC[element]) for element in DIC]` is a list.

*Note that getting keys to then re-access the dictionary is unnecessary. So is casting the values to tuples (they are already tuples). `list(DIC.values())` would produce the same result as the above list comprehension.*

Apart from that, what you are trying to achieve is unclear. You seem to have dictionary of tuples with keys corresponding to the one-based positions in the 5x6 matrix.  IF that is the case, you could get the intended result like this:

```
position = [[DIC[r+c+1] for c in range(w)] for r in range(0,w*h,w) ]
print(position)

[[(0.0, 0.0),  (0.14, 0.0),  (0.28, 0.0),  (0.42, 0.0),  (0.56, 0.0)],
 [(0.0, 0.14), (0.14, 0.14), (0.28, 0.14), (0.42, 0.14), (0.56, 0.14)], 
 [(0.0, 0.28), (0.14, 0.28), (0.28, 0.28), (0.42, 0.28), (0.56, 0.28)], 
 [(0.0, 0.42), (0.14, 0.42), (0.28, 0.42), (0.42, 0.42), (0.56, 0.42)], 
 [(0.0, 0.56), (0.14, 0.56), (0.28, 0.56), (0.42, 0.56), (0.56, 0.56)],
 [(0.0, 0.7),  (0.14, 0.7),  (0.28, 0.7),  (0.42, 0.7),  (0.56, 0.71)]]
```

If the keys in the dictionary are not based on the coordinates and you only want the values to be assigned sequentially, you could use an iterator on DIC.values():

```
iDIC = iter(DIC.values()) 
position = [[next(iDIC) for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h) ]
```

*This gives the same result but is not dependent on any relationship between keys and positions (it only depends on the order within the dictionary)*